# Application server role-based access controll

Tags: java, websphere-8, application-server

I'm working on implementing a role-based authorization service under WS Liberty.
There are two main goals:

- if the user without the correct user group tries to open a restricted url, show an error page
- the user should see a menu, listing all pages available for him

My question is: are there best practices to implement this behaviour? Should I create the first part in server.xml AND the second part in the appropriate view?
(this way the "logic" will be stored in two different parts of the code, and for example if I have to add a new URL, I have to insert it into two different places)

So is there a way to store this role-URL mapping in one place?

Thanks,
krisy

Answer (score 0):

In you application you can protect links checking roles (pseudo code, some frameworks have already custom tags for it):

```
if(request.isUserInRole("roleX")) {
  // render menu item for roleX
}
```

By default, if user is already logged in and tries to access page that is restricted for him, he will receive `403 Not authorized`, you can provide error page for that code via `web.xml` configuration.

In the `server.xml` via `Application binding` element you provide only mapping from your application roles to groups defined in the registry. Depending on the registry type you will be able to add/remove users to the given group granting or rejecting them right for example via `server.xml` or LDAP management tool in case of LDAP registry.

Comment: Yes, this is the programatic way to protect the code (the opposite way is to define procedural roles). This only solves the first goal, but not both of them at the same time. I'm looking for a solution which solves both of them.

Comment: @krisy What you mean by procedural roles? I forgot to mention that you need also to define security constraints in web.xml that would protect your resources. You use programmatic security to only hide parts of the interface that shouldnt be visible.